# Why does updating Xcode make my computer so slow?

Tags: macos, xcode, performance

I updated Xcode. Now some things take forever to run.

```
$ time make -n
make: Nothing to be done for `update'.

real    0m30.069s
user    0m0.011s
sys     0m0.025s
```

Likewise Python:

```
$ time ./foo.py
Terminated: 15

real    3m0.015s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.006s
```

foo.py looks like:

```js
#!/usr/bin/python
print 'hello, world'
```

This happened the last time I updated Xcode. The problem went away by itself after a day or so, but I'd rather not be dead in the water for the next day or so.

I'm running 10.14.5 (18F203) on a 2018 Macbook Pro

Comment: Can you add some more info? Such as did you run the Xcode post updating? Completed any command line tools installation? Did you restart your computer post installation? etc.

Comment: I rebooted my computer and the problem went away. I'll leave it at that. I'll leave this here for others to find. If there's a vote to close, I won't object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run Xcode post updating to make sure any post installation scripts get a chance to run.

After that, restart your Mac and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Rebooting seems to have fixed it. I'm letting xcode run as well. I hope I don't regret that.